# process nodejs data with php and goback

Tags: php, node.js, callback, process-management

actually i have a WORKER.PHP that recieve some post variables and a zip file with a 10k+ data row (csv) then insert the tiny result on mysql, on the other side i have a main page with an ajax call every 5 seconds to a secondary php script than just reply that mysql data in json

i spent a lot of months to develop the php code to parse and process a lot of hated math formulas to give a friendly result and also with extreme efficiency,  i'm not able at all to port this big script to javascript so...

Is there a way to recive the same data  through nodejs, send this data to a php script, wait for the response (data response,fail, error) and the send this response for all clients conected?

This pic might help

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example with this you can run cli php: http://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html

Comment: thanks, i found this article about your suggest http://www.scriptol.com/javascript/nodejs-php.php